# Include DONE from TODO items in agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have some recurring tasks for habits that I want to disappear after setting them done, but I also want a special agenda view, showing when items were completed, to see how well I have been keeping up with them. Say that my recurring tasks looks like this:

```
* TODO scheduled task
SCHEDULED: <2020-04-06 Mon ++1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2020-04-05 Sun 11:12]
:END:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-04-05 Sun 11:12]
* TODO task <2020-04-06 Mon ++1d>
  :PROPERTIES:
  :LAST_REPEAT: [2020-04-05 Sun 11:12]
  :END:
  - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-04-05 Sun 11:12]
```

After reading through different questions on this site I tried:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("1" agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps t)))
      ("2" agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps t)
        (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode t)
        (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode-items '(state closed clock))))))
```

Both solutions shows the same result, and has two problems:

The tasks shows up twice, I would like to match only against the STATE "DONE" from "TODO" line.

The tasks are shown as TODO in both cases but I want them shown as DONE.

Comment: Recurring tasks are never DONE, so you can't have them shown as DONE. What you want to show is their recent history. That may be possible, but I don't know how off the top of my head. Perhaps, store the state changes in a LOGBOOK drawer and see if there are any facilities to show/search the drawer contents.