# Seeking some continuity in agenda display following transition from TODO to DONE

Tags: org-agenda

With the file `~/tasks/theta.org`

```
* DONE Implement this.
CLOSED: [2023-01-16 Mon 17:58]
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2023-01-16 Mon 17:58]
:END:
* TODO Implement that.
```

and the `.emacs` file (using
[this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html)
suggested abbreviation):

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO(t)" "WAIT(w@/!)" "|" "DONE(d!)" "CANCELED(c@)")))
(setq org-log-done t)
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") #'org-agenda)
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/tasks/theta.org"))
```

I am logging the date when a task switched to `DONE` (hence the `CLOSED` and the "drawer" lines).

When I launch <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-agenda` followed by `n` (or <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> using the key mapping in the `.emacs` above), I only see the `TODO` items.

```
Week-agenda (W03):
Monday     16 January 2023 W03
Tuesday    17 January 2023
Wednesday  18 January 2023
Thursday   19 January 2023
Friday     20 January 2023
Saturday   21 January 2023
Sunday     22 January 2023

================================================================================
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
  theta:      TODO Implement that.
```

I don't just want the `DONE` items to vanish from the agenda. I would like some continuity in the agenda display following transition from TODO to DONE.

How can I display (last week's) DONE tasks in the global list of items?

Related:

- [The global TODO list](https://orgmode.org/manual/Global-TODO-list.html)
- [How can I see a list of DONE tasks in org-agenda sorted by closed date?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/73602/28733)
- [Why isn't org-agenda skipping DONE tasks?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/61253/28733)
- [Display "DONE" tasks of a specific day](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/52397/28733)
- [Org-mode agenda: Show list of tasks done in the past, and not those clocked](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/52994/28733)
- [Include DONE from TODO items in agenda](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/57598/28733)

Comment: What does `C-c a n` do? It is undefined in general. You have probably defined it in your `org-agenda-custom-commands`. Add the value of that variable (or at least the `n` part of it) to your question.

Comment: @NickD I did indeed map, as is customary, `C-c a` to `org-agenda`. This is in the `.emacs` in the question (the question is self-contained). The additional `n` is just one of the (main) suffixes to the `C-c a` prelude.

Comment: @NickD Thanks. I clarified the question.

Comment: When I do `C-c a` which I too have bound to `org-agenda`, there is *no* `n` option after that for me. That's why I asked for clarification (which you still have not provided). How is it defined in your case? I surmised that you have customized `org-agenda-custom-commands` to define that. Please add the value of that variable to your question.

Comment: @NickD That's odd. Can you do `C-h k C-c a` and look at the resulting page? There are many sequel commands (`t`, `T`, `m`, ..., `C), but the very first one (at least for `org-version` 9.5.5) is `a`.

Comment: Who is talking about `a`? You were talking about `n`: "...When I launch `M-x org-agenda` followed by `n`..." is what you said.